# Is it possible to open new activity from a fragment without trigger button?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

This is my code to open new activity from a fragment by using a button.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);

    Button newActivity = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.click);
    newActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            goToActivity();
        }
    });
    return v;
}

public void goToActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

Is it possible to open new activity from a fragment without a trigger button?? Because I have facing a lot of error when open new activity and close fragment activity directly like this :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);

    goToActivity();
    return v;
}

public void goToActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

EDIT :
Adding error log

```
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501): Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41b682e0 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41b682e0 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment$LoadPanoramaJSON.onPreExecute(HomeFragment.java:95)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:75)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-14 11:52:45.394: E/WindowManager(3501):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501): Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41a37398 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41a37398 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment$LoadPanoramaJSON.onPreExecute(HomeFragment.java:95)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:75)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-14 11:52:45.404: E/WindowManager(3501):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501): Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41bd4ed8 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41bd4ed8 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment$LoadPanoramaJSON.onPreExecute(HomeFragment.java:95)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:75)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-14 11:52:45.414: E/WindowManager(3501):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501): Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41bbadd0 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41bbadd0 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment$LoadPanoramaJSON.onPreExecute(HomeFragment.java:95)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:75)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-14 11:52:45.424: E/WindowManager(3501):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501): Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41c2cf80 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41c2cf80 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment$LoadPanoramaJSON.onPreExecute(HomeFragment.java:95)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:75)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-14 11:52:45.434: E/WindowManager(3501):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501): Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41c00460 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41c00460 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment$LoadPanoramaJSON.onPreExecute(HomeFragment.java:95)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:75)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501): Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41cd3e60 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41cd3e60 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment$LoadPanoramaJSON.onPreExecute(HomeFragment.java:95)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:75)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-14 11:52:45.444: E/WindowManager(3501):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501): Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41ce2fa8 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41ce2fa8 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment$LoadPanoramaJSON.onPreExecute(HomeFragment.java:95)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:75)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501): Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41c66798 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.arbalest.example.NewActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41c66798 that was originally added here
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment$LoadPanoramaJSON.onPreExecute(HomeFragment.java:95)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at com.arbalest.example.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:75)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-14 11:52:45.464: E/WindowManager(3501):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

..and a lot more..

Comment: Giving error messages is better than just saying 'facing a lot of errors'

Comment: Sorry for pending post error log. I'm new here, need to figure out how to post a long log :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  you do not need to call `.finish()` on your activity in this way. The android Activity lifecycle handles this for you automatically.
When you start a new activity with `startActivity(intent)` the previous activity will automatically have it's lifecycle methods called (initially `onPause()`, then `onStop()` etc).

Secondly, a Fragment is displayed by an Activity. Why would you want a Fragment to start a different Activity as soon as the Fragment's view is created? I think you may need to read further about the [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) lifecycles.

---

Additional:
When you start a new activity, the previous activity gets added to the backstack. You can think of the backstack as a history for the activities in your app. Each time you hit the back button, you go back in the app's activity history. You can stop an activity from being added to the backstack by setting `android:noHistory=true"` for that particular activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<activity
            android:name="xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"  
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: Wow, it works! But how to prevent the last activity to calling again using back button??
I need to split into 2 activities, because on the 1st activity I need to run on fullscreen mode (no title bar) and then use title bar mode on 2nd activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the goToActivity() method from within onResume().

Comment: I failed to mention that your problem is that you are finishing the activity before returning the activity's view thus failing to meet the onCreateView contract.